# Android Studio Gradle offline Gradle Cache

Tags: gradle, offline

Android Studio Version 3.1.3

Issue:
Gradle wants to re-download dependencies that were previously downloaded

For instance: "No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 available for offline mode."

It doesn't matter which version I use, it refuses to accept the ones located at "/~.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/"

I have specified gradle service directory path (where the downloaded dependencies are) and ticked the "Offline work" option. I've tried using the default gradle distribution and a local gradle distribution "gradle-4.8.1-bin".

Am I missing something?

Does that mean that gradle only uses per-project cache? Do I have to download dependencies every time that I create a new project?

If so, is that a way to use the already downloaded dependencies?

Also, may I ask why does Android Studio has a tick option to "Work offline"? What is it used for?

Comment: The error: "Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V"

Comment: I also want to build cache offline . But not get success yet.. have you done it??